# Why doesn't the class attribute update when I change the input value? Tkinter Python 3

Tags: dataframe, class, search, tkinter, attributes

I am trying to develop a simple application with tkinter and I want to create a class that performs a search in a dataframe, the search's value it is linked to the information typed in an entry that belongs to another class, however when I run the code, the value of the search is not modified when changing the value of the input. Here the code so far

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

cat = {'N°_Cel': pd.Series(['3007441467', '3164992937', '3212400100', '3258172402', '3169995802'], index= [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), 
                     'Names': pd.Series(['Jairo Moreno', 'Laura Mesa', 'Camilo Baquero', 'Daniela Smith', 'Ximena Sterling'], index= [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), 
                     'Adress': pd.Series(['Cll 158 # 96A 25','Cll 132 # 100A 63', 'Cll 158 # 100A 63', 'Cll 148 # 97A 41', 'Cll 172A # 8 20'], index= [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), 
                                             'Schedule': pd.Series(['N.A.', 'Evening.', 'N.A.', 'After 14', 'Morning'], index= [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), 
                                             'Payment': pd.Series(['Credit', 'Cash', 'Credit', 'Credit', 'Cash'], index= [0, 1, 2, 3, 4])}
customer_cat = pd.DataFrame(cat)

class Search_Client():
       def __init__(self, info, dataframe, colname):
           self.info = info
           self.dataframe = dataframe
           self.colname = colname

       def search(self):
           if self.info == '':
               result = ''
           else:
               result = self.dataframe.loc[self.dataframe[self.colname]==self.info]
               if result.empty == True:
                   result = ''
               else:
                   results = result
                   print(results)

class Order_Document():
    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.geometry('')
        self.parent.title('Order document')
        self.cellphone_number = StringVar()

        Label(self.parent, text= 'Order Document', bg= 'light gray', font= 'Verdana 13', relief= RIDGE).grid(row= 0, column= 0, columnspan= 3) # Se debe centrar al finalizar el diseño de la ventana                

        Label(self.parent, text= 'Cellphone Number: ', bg = 'white smoke', font= 'Arial 11 bold', justify= 'left').grid(row= 5, column= 0, sticky= 'we')    
        Entry(self.parent, textvariable= self.cellphone_number, font= 'Arial 11').grid(row=5, column= 1, sticky= 'we')    

        self.search_client = Search_Client(self.cellphone_number.get(), customer_cat, 'N°_Cel')
        Button(self.parent, text= 'Buscar', command= self.search_client.search, bg= 'gold', font= 'Verdana 13').grid(row= 5, column= 3, sticky= 'we')       

app = Tk()
ejec = Order_Document(app)
app.mainloop()
```

I don't know what I could be doing wrong, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Why would it get changed? Should they be linken in any way? `entry.get()` might help.

Comment: Yes, the idea is that the class make the search depending the data in the entry, but its take the entry's data when its initializate the code (empty) and does not update if change the value of the entry, i mean, it doesnt make a new search